# Using the Windows 8 SDK to compile for Windows 7

Tags: windows, winapi, compilation, zlib

(This question uses zlib as an example but isn't specific to it.)

I'm trying to compile zlib on Windows using the MSVC project file it comes with. I'm using VS2012 with the Windows 8 SDK, but my build machine is Windows 7.

Zlib contains the following code:

```
#ifdef IOWIN32_USING_WINRT_API
    if ((filename!=NULL) && (dwDesiredAccess != 0))
        hFile = CreateFile2((LPCTSTR)filename, dwDesiredAccess, dwShareMode, dwCreationDisposition, NULL);
#else
    if ((filename!=NULL) && (dwDesiredAccess != 0))
        hFile = CreateFile((LPCTSTR)filename, dwDesiredAccess, dwShareMode, NULL, dwCreationDisposition, dwFlagsAndAttributes, NULL);
#endif
```

where IOWIN32_USING_WINRT_API is set up as follows

```
#if defined(WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION) && (!(defined(IOWIN32_USING_WINRT_API)))
#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_APP)
#define IOWIN32_USING_WINRT_API 1
#endif
#endif
```

WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION and WINAPI_PARTITION_APP are defined in the Windows 8 SDK (winapifamily.h), so the result is that the code that uses CreateFile2 in zlib is available to be compiled.

I can compile zlib, but any application that tries to load it fails because it can't find CreateFile2, and rightly so, since my machine is Windows 7 and that API was introduced in Windows 8.

This is the first time I've ever used a Windows SDK on a lower version of Windows than it supports, hence my question:

Is my only recourse to patch zlib to add a check for _WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8 to the very first line, and pass /D_WIN32_WINNT=_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7 to msbuild? That would mean I'd have to build two sets of binaries - one that supports Win7 (by passing the /D) and one that supports Win8 (by not passing the /D).

Is there no way to have a common binary that works on both Windows 7 and 8 and uses the CreateFile2 codepath if running on Windows 8? (I suppose that way is GetProcAddress + function pointers. Anything else?)

Comment: Actually, the Win7 library will work fine on Win8 for desktop apps. `CreateFile` is only disable for WinRT aka "Windows Store" apps.

Comment: So just to confirm, was I mistaken to believe that the Win8 SDK can be used to compile programs unchanged for both Win7 and Win8? If I want to target Windows version X, am I always supposed to use the SDK version X rather than a later SDK?

Comment: No, see my answer. What I meant is you can use `/D_WIN32_WINNT=_WIN32_WINNT_WIN7` to build a Win7 library and then use it in both OS.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `_WIN32_WINNT` to select which OS version you want to target. It's the zlib check which is broken. `WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP` includes `WINAPI_FAMILY_APP` so their check always succeeds. You can fix it like:

```
#if defined(WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION) && (!(defined(IOWIN32_USING_WINRT_API)))
#if WINAPI_FAMILY_ONE_PARTITION(WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP, WINAPI_PARTITION_APP)
#define IOWIN32_USING_WINRT_API 1
#endif
#endif
```

See here for more info: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/3965645c-978c-4148-b32c-1853f7fd22b3

Comment: Thanks for confirming that the /D is required.

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong. I think you also need to add a condition to the first #if in your answer to check for _WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8. Please confirm.

Answer (score 4):

This question is old but if anyone still has this problem, I just succeded building latest zlib with msvc 12.0 targeting windows 7 by modifying the code in (iowin32.c file line 28) like so:

```
#if _WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8
#if defined(WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION) && (!(defined(IOWIN32_USING_WINRT_API)))
#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_APP)
#define IOWIN32_USING_WINRT_API 1
#endif
#endif
#endif
```

of course to make this work you need to define a macro in:
configuration properties >C/C++ > preprocessor:

```
_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601
```

which means you're targeting windows 7 (if using windows 7 SDK this is not needed)

then *rebuilding* the project with success :)
and yes, of course this fix is only aplicable if you're using a windows older
than windows 8.

however this is not the only error that zlib has, you will for sure encounter a mismatched version in zlib.def file.
to fix this open the zlib.def file that contains the error and replace **1.2.8** with **1.28**
or whatever the version is

Comment: That is correct. It's the same thing we do at the gtk-win32 project: https://github.com/hexchat/gtk-win32/tree/master/zlib/contrib/vstudio/vc12

Answer (score 2):

You can do this is you have at least the Update 1 installed for VS2012 because this gives you the ability to compile for XP, which links against a cut down version of the Windows 7 SDK.

We do this with some of our code and it is compatible across XP, Windows 7 and Windows 8.

See the [MSDN blog here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/06/15/10320645.aspx) for details.

Crucial information below

[image: msdn]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way is to use `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` -- you can also see this in MFC Sources which handle messages native to WIn7 (or later)

e.g.: `CWnd::OnGesture()` in `%VCINSTALLDIR%atlmfc\src\mfc\wincore.cpp`