# Calling any cURL function results in "entry point not found" when executing the program

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012, curl, libcurl

In Visual Studio 2012 (SP4) if I create a new Windows EXE solution, use the Nuget command line to "install-package curl", build the solution, the program executes correctly and displays the simple window as expected.

If I add a call to `curl_version()` to the code (meaning the cURL, SSL, etc... DLLs are now referenced) - I get an error from Windows saying...

```
MyProgram.EXE - Entry Point Not Found
The procedure entry point CreateFile2 could not be located in the 
dynamic link library KERNEL32.DLL.
```

I've used Dependency Walker to verify that the DLLs (LIBCURL, LIBSSH2, SSLEAY32 and ZLIB.DLL) are the same ones Nuget installed - and they are.

Help please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17102770/using-the-windows-8-sdk-to-compile-for-windows-7) solution - basically zLIB v1.2.8.1 references the Windows 8 function CreateFile2